# Not able to save data in H2 Database using SpringBootTest and Spring JPA Repository

Tags: spring, database, spring-security, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am using @SpringBootTest to test SpringSecurity basic authentication.When I test it,the h2 database does not save the data.I do not see the insert statement in the console,which I apparently see when I am running my actual SpringBoot Application and inserting the data from frontend. Please help.

Below is my test:

```
        @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
        @ContextConfiguration(classes=ConnectionsAppApplication.class)
        @Transactional
        public class AuthenticationTest {

            @Autowired
            private WebApplicationContext context;

            private MockMvc mockMvc;

            @Mock
            CustDetailsRepository custRepository;

            @Mock
            BCryptPasswordEncoder encrypt;

            @InjectMocks
            CustomerServiceImpl customerServiceImpl;



           @BeforeEach
           public void setup() {

             MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
             mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
           }


          @Test
          void testAuthentication() {

              CustomerDetails customer = new CustomerDetails();
              customer.setEmailid("abc.com");
              customer.setPassword("abc@123456");
              customerServiceImpl.saveUser(customer);
           try {
               this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/login")
               .with(httpBasic("abc.com","abc@123456")))
               .andDo(print())
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andReturn();
           } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

       }
```

saveUser method in CustomerServiceImpl class:

```
        public void saveUser(CustomerDetails customerDetails) {
          customerDetails.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(customerDetails.getPassword()));
          custDetailsRepository.save(customerDetails);
         }
```

Comment: You are mocking your repository. How can you expect anything to be saved in the DB?

Comment: @Lesiak Am I doing something wrong? Can you please correct me? How will mocking a SpringJPA repository fail to save data.

Comment: Mock is a dummy object that you use instead of real implementation to simplify your tests - you tell it what method will be called on it and what to answer (Mockito answers null by default if no expectations were set). If you call `custDetailsRepository.save` on a mock no call to the db will be made. Now it is up to you to decide if you want to use h2 or mocked repository in your test. Nice mockito tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series

Comment: I converted my service customerServiceImpl to an @autowired (integration testing) and now I can pass the test. However, I will check how to test the same using mockito, thanks a lot for this answer. It helped me :).

Comment: Note that if you want to replace some real Bean in a test with a Mock in a SpringBootTest, you need to use a `@MockBean` annotation (not `@Mock`). Also, do not use `@InjectMocks` annotations.

Comment: Noted. Thank you ^^)

Comment: If the answer helps, please be so kind to accept / upvote it (or both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to implement this test:

**Option 1: use real h2**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ConnectionsAppApplication.class)
@Transactional
public class AuthenticationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    CustomerServiceImpl customerServiceImpl;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }


    @Test
    void testAuthentication() {

        CustomerDetails customer = new CustomerDetails();
        customer.setEmailid("abc.com");
        customer.setPassword("abc@123456");
        customerServiceImpl.saveUser(customer);
        try {
             this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/login")
                 .with(httpBasic("abc.com","abc@123456")))
                 .andDo(print())
                 .andExpect(status().isOk())
                 .andReturn();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Mock your service / repository**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ConnectionsAppApplication.class)
@Transactional
public class AuthenticationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    CustomerServiceImpl customerServiceImpl;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }


    @Test
    void testAuthentication() {
        // set expectations on CustomerServiceImpl
        CustomerDetails customer = new CustomerDetails();
        customer.setEmailid("abc.com");
        customer.setPassword("abc@123456");
        // mock the method you use to fetch the customer
        when(customerServiceImpl.getUser("abc.com").thenReturn(customer);
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/login")
                .with(httpBasic("abc.com","abc@123456")))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
           } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
}
```

Note that you also can use @WebMvcTest to test only the web slice of your app (meaning no other beans will be instantiated, for example all sercies you depend in the controller must be delivered by @MockBean)

Comment: I used the first one. Thanks.